# PHP cURL not loading Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: php, windows, curl

I'm running Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4.9 under Windows 8 64-bit.
Trying to enable cURL extension for PHP but it's not loading.

I have tried:

- Uncommented the line where the modules load in php.ini (yes, the correct INI-file)
- Copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to C:\Windows and C:\Windows\System32
- Replaced php_curl.dll with the one from: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ (I know it's not the correct version, but worth a try)

Is it the DLL-file that's the problem? Where can I find something that will work with my setup?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, adding C:\PHP to the PATH in Windows was the solution.