# How can I load curl mod in Windows with Apache and PHP?

Tags: php, apache, curl, fastcgi, windows-server-2012

I use Windows Server 2012 core + Apache 2.4(x64)+ PHP5.5(x64) to run a web service.

Everything is OK initially, but when I use the curl mod, it doesn't work.

The PHP error_log display this error:

> Call to undefined function `curl_init()`

I tried to follow the instructions in this post: [PHP cURL not loading Windows 8 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047746/php-curl-not-loading-windows-8-64-bit)

1 Copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to C:\Windows and C:\Windows\System32 doesn't work
2.add httpd.conf this (LoadFile C:/php55/libeay32.dll LoadFile        C:/php55/ssleay32.dll) doesn't work

Then in the cmd window, I tried using php.exe test.php and the curl works OK.

If I use apache2.4 + fcgi, it also works OK.

But when I use apache + php_mod, it doesn't work anymore.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, by adding `C:\PHP` to the `PATH` in Windows.

Because I use core, so first add is not successful. I used this:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT where "name='path' and username='<system>'" set VariableValue="%path%;c:\php"
```